# Scrape a website with hidden parameters using the requests library

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, python-requests

So I am trying to **scrape** the following [webpage](https://member.expireddomains.net/domains/pendingdelete/?o=statustld_registered&r=d) which protected by a login page. None the less when I run the code it keeps redirecting me to the login page. I think this might be due to the fact that the login page has a hidden parameter, though I don't really know how to integrate it into my payloads. Here below is the code I wrote.

```
import requests

payloads = {"login": "pythonusername3" ,
"password": "pythonpassword3" }

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.post('https://member.expireddomains.net/login/', data=payloads)
    get = session.get("https://member.expireddomains.net/domains/pendingdelete/?o=statustld_registered&r=d").text
    print(get)
```

Comment: You have to use field name, not id - `data = {'login':usr, 'password':pwd}`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please finish the tour. Valid SO question. End of reviewing. Enjoy SO ;-)

Comment: try to actually login the website on any browser and check whether any cookies are stored using developer tools, usually after login some cookies are added to browser for user authentication.

Comment: @Gaur93 doesn’t requests.session() solve this problem?

Comment: @t.m.adam oh I see thanks I just changed the dictionary key to the name instead of Id but It is still incapable of loging in the websit

Comment: Why not? I managed to login with your code (using the `data` dict i described in my previous comment). Can you update your question with your current code?

Comment: @t.m.adam I just updated the code, did I do something wrong?

Comment: No, your code is fine. How do you know that the login is unsuccessful? Don't you get `True` with `print('Your username' in get)`?

Comment: @t.m.adam I think it is not logged in as the code keeps returning the scrap of the Login page. When I run print(“Your username” in get) I get False.

Comment: Just to be clear, "Your username" is your actual username as you see it in your browser (capitalisation is important), right? I don't get it, your code works fine for me!

Comment: @t.m.adam yes, to make it easier I have created a throwaway account on the website, with the username : pythonusername and password: pythonpassword. So this is how my code looks (I updated the code).

Comment: @t.m.adam oh my bad there was a problem with the throwaway account give me a second I will creat a new one

Comment: @t.m.adam so the usernane is pythonusername3 and the password is pythonpassword3 (I updated my code)

Comment: Yep, this works - `print('Pythonusername3' in get)` prints `True`. I also saved the html and opened it in the browser and it is the `/domains/pendingdelete/` page. I have no idea why it doesn't work for you, sorry.

Comment: @t.m.adam ooooh prints True I misunderstood you last time when you asked me to print(“Your username” in get) I literally wrote print(“Your username” in get)

Comment: @t.m.adam it work now thanks a ton! Though I don’t quite get why it didn’t work before.

Comment: Because the POST data should be `field_name=field_value`. The id is used mostly by js and css. So mystery solved, have a nice day!

Comment: @t.m.adam oh I see well thank you very much for your help, though In what case should I include the hidden parameters ( on this website there where a few hidden parameters but we didn’t mention any)

Comment: You can find hidden fields if you inspect the html. Look for `<input type=hidden name="some_name" value="some value">`

Comment: @t.m.adam yeah I know, what I am trying to say is that the website I was trying to login had hidden fields, but we didn't include them in the payloads

Comment: You mean this: `<input name="searchinit" value="1" type="hidden">`? It's not important, you can leve it out, it makes no difference. But yes, usually you have to submit hidden fields.

Comment: @t.m.adam if we were to include this field would we put it in payloads such as "searchinit" : "1"?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The `data` dictionary should contain a `'name':'value'` item for every input.

Comment: @t.m.adam great thanks a lot for your help

Comment: You're very welcome @Fozoro

Answer (score 0):

I used PhantomJS web driver to click the login form instead, and then send the cookies to requests module.

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path = r'./phantomjs')
site = 'https://www.wanikani.com/login'

print 'Opening ' + site
driver.get(site)
```

driver.find_element_by_id("user_login").send_keys("usernamexxxx")

driver.find_element_by_id("user_password").send_keys("passwordxxx")
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("button").click()

```
cookie = driver.get_cookies()
s = requests.Session()

c = [s.cookies.set(c['name'], c['value']) for c in cookie]
```

https://community.wanikani.com/t/userscript-burn-manager-review-resurrect-retire/13001/56?u=polv